# Portainer: Pass vm.max_map_count to SonarQube Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, elasticsearch, sysctl

I need to set up a SonarQube container on my Portainer instance. SonarQube uses Elasticsearch, which needs a kernel setting passed from the host. This issue is [well](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/requirements/requirements/) [documented](https://github.com/docker-library/elasticsearch/issues/111), as mentioned in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/956361/kubernetes-docker-and-vm-max-map-count), but unfortunately the poster did not detail their solution.

Apparently, this issue can be fixed by running this on your host(?)

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

However, I'd like it if there were a way to specify this for this container only. Is such a thing possible, and how is it done in Portainer? I tried an environment variable, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Containers share the machine’s OS system kernel and therefore it is not possible to change Kernel parameters like `vm.max_map_count` in the container itself.

The [issue](https://github.com/docker-library/elasticsearch/issues/111) you linked contains a sample command

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged --net=host --pid=host -v /:/host debian:sid chroot /host sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262145
```

how to do this when starting the container. However I wouldn't recommend doing this as the `privileged` mode is not safe.

I would recommend to set the `vm.max_map_count` on the host and pin the container to that Docker host with your cluster manager. IMHO it would also make sense to run elasticsearch and sonarqube in dedicated containers.

Comment: how would i pass it to a deployment to k8s ? is it an environment ?